# Is there any way to make a webpage as a spreadsheet in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jqgrid, spreadsheet

I want to make a webpage that will act as a spreadsheet where I can add more cells like having same functionality as a excelsheet and can also save my file to the database. 
I have used 'spreadsheet', 'axlsx' gems but they all export the excel file rather than making a webpage of it.

Comment: Rails cannot do this. You need JavaScript.

Comment: Please put some amount of effort into this. StackOverflow isn't a place for others to do work for you, it's a community that is happy to help you solve a specific problem though.

Comment: Why don't you just design page which will look like like `spreadsheet`, create buttons with the help of `javascript` which will allow you to clone column and rows, and add `buttons` to save that data to your database. So easy get started

Comment: You can use `clone()` jquery function to make clone of textfields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have integrated it successfully using 'jqgrid-jquery-rails' with the help of jqgrid plugin. and exactly make the functionality like spreadsheet acts.

Answer (score 1):

Add the gem 'jqgrid-jquery-rails', '~> 4.6.001' in the gemfile.

Also gem "jquery-ui-rails" is required.

For the demo,

You can add scaffold of invoices having migration fields as

class CreateInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

```
create_table :invoices do |t|
  t.integer   'invid'
  t.datetime  'invdate'
  t.float     'amount'
  t.float     'tax'
  t.float     'total'
  t.string    'note'
end
```

end

Then in the index page of the invoices, write this code for the demo purpose.

```
<br /><br />

<input type="button" value="Edit in Batch Mode" onclick="startEdit()" />
<input type="button" value="Save All Rows" onclick="saveRows()" />

<br /><br />

<table id="jqGrid"></table>
<div id="jqGridPager"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: "/invoices",
            editurl: ' /invoices/update_all_row',
            datatype: "json",
            colModel: [
                {
                    label: "Inv No.",
                    name: "id",
                    width: 75
                },
                {
                    label: "Date",
                    name: 'invdate',
                    width: 140,
                    editable: true // must set editable to true if you want to make the field editable
                },
                {
                    label: "Amount",
                    name: 'amount',
                    width: 100,
                    editable: true
                },
                {
                    label : "Tax",
                    name: 'tax',
                    width: 120,
                    editable: true
                }
            ],
            sortname: 'Inv No',
            loadonce : true,
            viewrecords: true,
            onSelectRow: startEdit, // the javascript function to call on row click. will ues to to put the row in edit mode
            width: 780,
            height: 200,
            rowNum: 10,
            pager: "#jqGridPager",
            gridview: true
        });


        var lastSelection;

        function editRow(id) {
            if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
                var grid = $("#jqGrid");
                grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
                grid.jqGrid('editRow',id, {keys: true} );
                lastSelection = id;
            }
        }
    });


        function startEdit() {
            var grid = $("#jqGrid");
            var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                grid.jqGrid('editRow',ids[i]);
            }
        };
        function saveRows() {
          var grid = $("#jqGrid");
          var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

          for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            grid.jqGrid('saveRow', ids[i]);
          }
       }

</script>
```

You can see the spreadsheet like grid on the webpage. having lot of functionalities same as spreadsheet.

can add more functionalities from http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/